# Cannot Create mylsq user and password using ssh on remote server

Tags: mysql

when running the below command I get error. I am trying to create a bash script

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/cmm.key root@192.168.1.55 "mysql -u root -p'0tYP62V40szokdzxGRXTLT4Czrg' -e 'CREATE USER sial@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'sial@123';'"
```

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'sial@123' at line 1

Tried with escape

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/cmm.key root@192.168.1.55 "mysql -u root -p'0tYP62V40szokdzxGRXTLT4Czrg' -ev 'CREATE USER \'sial\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY \'sial@123\';'"
```

Error

ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'CREATE USER sial@localhost IDENTIFIED BY /sial@123/;

Comment: You should add some escaping to that string, eg. through `IDENTIFIED BY \'sial@123\'`

Comment: tried but doesnt work

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried? Is there a new error message?

Comment: when I go for verbose mode I see

ssh -i ~/.ssh/cmm.key root@192.168.1.55 "mysql -u root -p'0tYP62V40szokdzxGRXTLT4Czrg' -ev 'CREATE USER sial@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'sial@123';'"
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'CREATE USER sial@localhost IDENTIFIED BY sial@123;'

Comment: Please add all such clarification to the question itself, not to the comment section. The given command still does not use any escapiing

Comment: ok I did as said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create one shell script.
use backquotes inside script

mycommand.sh

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/cmm.key root@192.168.1.55 `mysql -u root -p'0tYP62V40szokdzxGRXTLT4Czrg' -e "CREATE USER sial@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'sial@123';"`
```

then run the shell script like this,
sh mycommand.sh

Comment: It works but it does login into the other server. I dont want to get logged in their instead it should execute on source server itself.

Comment: no I am triyng to execute this command without actually navigating to the destination server. See the below command I executed and it works without actually navigating to destination server.

ssh -i ~/.ssh/cmm.key root@$destination_ip "mysql -u root -p'0tYP62V40szokdzxGRXTLT4Czrg' -e 'CREATE DATABASE sial /*\!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;'"